# How to add my app as a camera app on Android's action picker

Tags: android

I would like to add my camera app as one of the items on Action Picker for taking photos. An example would be when I select to send a photo taken with a camera on WhatsApp, I can choose a third party app like Camera 360, other than the default camera app.

Below was added to *AndroidManifest.xml*, but it did not do anything.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Would there be any other way of doing so? I looked at the manifest of Camera 360, but could not find anything that seemed relevant to the issue.